# How to calculate the volume between these two cylinders and the mass of the given body?

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

Below I stated 2 equations which is my contribution to the solution, What should I  do next ?

[image: data]
[image: equation1]

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html

Comment: Aha. I did not know.